# REST API URL for VMC PUSH

Tags: cloud-foundry

This question is regarding REST API URL for use with curl equivalent to VMC push for a new application.

I have referred the api documentation of cloud foundry at http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.com/http-apps for various REST API URL mapping to vmc commands. However, I did not find a REST API URL for pushing a new application. I have tried deploying a new application with the POST html request but that returns a 504 BAD GATEWAY response. below is the curl command:

```
curl --request POST http://api.cloudfoundry.com/apps --data @data.json --header "Authorization: bearer token"
```

Content of data.json are as follows:

```
{"name": "mywebapp45",  "staging": {"model": "spring","stack": "java"}, "uris": [    "mywebapp45.cloudfoundry.com"], "instances": 1, "resources": {"memory": 256},"state": "STARTED"}`
```

and the web app archive is in the same directory from where I execute the curl command.

Any insight on this is much appreciated. Thanks a lot for the help in advance

Comment: Based on the using language, I'd like to try the cfoundry ruby client: https://rubygems.org/gems/cfoundry, the java client: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-java-client, or the Node.js client which can also be found in github.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the language, I'd like you to try the cfoundry ruby client: rubygems.org/gems/cfoundry, the java client: github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-java-client, or the Node.js client which can also be found in github.